# Rails: is there a model shortcut for listing my many "attr_accessible" + "validates :presence => true" attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In many of my rails models, I have a number of fields which are what I think of as "normal" model attributes, ie things which are set by the user, then later displayed, and are mandatory parts of a model instance.  It seems kind of overly verbose to have to always do this:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  attr_accessible :age
  attr_accessible :height

  validates :name, :presence => true
  validates :age, :presence => true
  validates :height, :presence => true
end
```

Ideally I'd like to just tell rails "everything but the auto-generated ID field should be validated present and accessible for mass assignment".  How can I do that, given that it's said to be bad security practice to just make everything available for mass assignment?

**Update**: The existing way also seems bad in that I type my list of attributes twice, which is quite error prone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define your own class method, say on `ActiveRecord::Base`:

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.validate_presence_and_make_accessible *args
    attr_accessible *args
    validates_presence_of *args
  end
end
```

Then in your models:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate_presence_and_make_accessible :name, :age, :height
end
```

I suck at naming methods sometime, btw.  Feel free to rename to something better.

Comment: *Protected* sort of indicates that those attributes are being protected while its actually the opposite. Although more verbose, I'd probably use something like `make_accessible_and_validate_presence`.

Answer (score 1):

A little less verbose way:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :age, :height
  validates :name, :age, :height, :presence => true
end
```

Specifying only protected attributes:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_protected :id
  validates :name, :age, :height, :presence => true
end
```

Comment: Hmm, my main bugbear was really that I have to type out the list of attributes twice, and that seems error prone... I'll rephrase question a bit to clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

This is simpler:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_protected :id
  validates_presence_of :name, :age, :height
end
```

And regarding your comment about security practice of mass assignments, I think you should read this: http://b.lesseverything.com/2008/3/11/use-attr_protected-or-we-will-hack-you

Comment: I think the blog you link is saying the same thing, only it's suggesting to use attr_protected on protected fields, rather than using attr_accessible on visible fields, right?  Doesn't that run a higher risk of forgetting to protect something, rather than protecting everything by default?

Comment: `attr_accessible` is a reasonable way to go as well.  It's simply a whitelist rather than a blacklist.

Comment: I wouldn't take that blog too literally. As one commenter points out, protecting attributes solves the problem, and the rest is not really adding value.